# How to configure fluentbit to send error log only

Tags: kubernetes, elk, fluent-bit

I am using fluentbit to send kubernetes logs to ELK , i have set the level to error but still it sends all the log msgs to ELK , How can I configure fluentbit to send msgs that correspond to some error only.

Answer (score 0):

In  official documentation for Kubernetes filter there is an example about how to make your Pod suggest a parser for your data based in an annotation: [Fluent Bit Filters](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/filter/kubernetes).

Under certain and not common conditions, a user would want to alter that hard-coded regular expression, for that purpose the option **Regex_Parser** can be used [Fluent Bit Regex](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/filter/parser).

Useful article: [Fluent Bit Article](https://supergiant.io/blog/exporting-kubernetes-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-fluent-bit/).